# using a text file to determine subdomain includes php

Tags: php, subdomain

Ok i have 2 files - index.php that has and if statement that is as follows:

```
    $sub = array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
    if ($sub == 'localhost') include 'home.php';
    if ($sub == 'whateversubdomain') include 'correspondingphpfile .php';
```

I also have a text file that has:

```
subdomain = subdomain.php
nextsub = nextsub.php
.... and so on
```

The question being how would I make it so that when I add a new line to the text file say nextsub, and someone visits nextsub.sitename.com that they are directed to the correct php file.

I was thinking of opening the text file and creating a variable in the index.php file then saying if $sub == $newVar include $subName . .php .

is this possible - something like -

```
//open file
$fp = @fopen ($some_file, "r");

if ($fp) {
     //for each line in file
     while(!feof($fp)) {
          //push lines into array
          $this_line = fgets($fp);                 
          array_push($some_array,$this_line);
     }
     //close file
     fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(you have to handle non-existing manually)

For example, a directory "subdomains":

```
$sub = array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
include 'subdomains/'.basename($sub).'.php';
```

I don't know, what's the point in additional writing into file.

Comment: you are right thanks... that was just the way I thought possible.

Comment: Check the elements count after exploding HTTP_HOST by dot.

Comment: so basically a if the length is equal to 0 then include home. what I did was make an if statement. if ($sub == 'localhost') include 'home.php';
if ($sub != 'localhost') include 'directory/'.basename($sub).'.php';

Comment: Not exactly: sub.example.org produces 3 elements, example.org produces 2. Think. [;

Comment: Thank you for your help, i am new at php. Why is 
'if ($sub == 'localhost') include 'home.php'; if ($sub != 'localhost') include 'directory/'.basename($sub).'.php'; '
incorrect it seems to be working?

Answer (score 0):

If you are insisting on having subdomains with pages that don’t have an easy to parse name scheme the best bet is the following:

```
// Create an array that maps subdomains to pages.
$sub_page_map = array();
$sub_page_map['localhost'] = 'home.php';
$sub_page_map['whateversubdomain'] = 'correspondingphpfile.php';

// Get the subdomain.  
$sub = array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));

// If the `$sub` exists in `$sub_page_map` then include the corresponding file.
if (array_key_exists($sub, $sub_page_map)) {
  include $sub_page_map[$sub];
}
else {
  include 'default.php';
}
```

If you want to store it in an external text file, just adapt your file parsing code to generate the values in `$sub_page_map`.  But to me the biggest flaw in your setup is the lack of a default page, which is why I included an `else` to load a proposed `` `default.php ``.